# Using Julia's external command interpolation inside macros?

Tags: julia

I have been trying to write a Julia macro that takes Cmd objects and runs them inside a loop. The catch is that I want to use the local loop variables for interpolation in the command. I would write a function and use eval(), but eval() uses the global scope and so can't see the local loop variables.

Below is a simple example that demonstrates how string interpolation works, but the command interpolation fails:

```
macro runcmd(cmdExpr)
    quote
        for i in 1:2
            println("i: $i")
            run($cmdExpr)
        end
    end
end
@runcmd(`echo $i`)
```

outputs

```
i: 1
ERROR: i not defined
 in anonymous at none:5
```

If I expand the macro I get

```
quote  # none, line 3:
    for #261#i = 1:2 # line 4:
        println("i: $#261#i") # line 5:
        run(Base.cmd_gen((("echo",),(i,))))
    end
end
```

I am guessing the #261# part that is missing from the cmd_gen argument's reference to i is related to the problem, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Just curious ... what's your use case and/or motivation for wanting to do this?

Comment: Have you read the macro hygiene part of the manual? The `i` in your `quote` is not going to appear literally as an `i` in the generated code.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I am running lots of shell commands each of which is over an array of possible datasets, and the commands need to reference the dataset name.

Comment: @IainDunning Thanks! I read the macro section and then skimmed the hygiene part since at the time I didn't understand how it applied. Now I see what was going on.

Comment: It is subtle! Any manual improvements you can suggest would be welcome I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the problem is because of the mismatch between the index `#261#i` and the reference to it in `echo $i`. An easy way to resolve the problem is to escape the `i` used in the index:

```
macro runcmd(cmdExpr)
    quote
        for $(esc(:i)) in 1:2
            println("i: $i")
            run($cmdExpr)
        end
    end
end
```

Then we get:

```
julia> @runcmd(`echo $i`)
i: 1
1
i: 2
2
```

There's more discussion in Julia's [metaprogramming documentation](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#hygiene).

Comment: I see now that #261#i means that i was made a local variable by the macro expander to prevent namespace collisions. Thanks for the answer and the link!